# Excel Querytable: adding a range parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Querytable linked to a cell value.
The Querytable creation works fine, I managed to find how to add a parameter, but now I can't find how to change the SQL statement.
When I run the example below, it genertes no error, but if I change the value in D1, I get the message 'No value given for one or more required parameters".

```
Sub AddParam()
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim prm As Parameter
    Set qt = ActiveSheet.QueryTables("705547512")
    qt.Parameters.Delete    'reset params
    Set prm = qt.Parameters.Add("dbk")
    prm.SetParam xlRange, Sheet2.Range("D1")
    prm.RefreshOnChange = True
    qt.CommandText = "select top 10 * from [Ledger account entries$b8:l300] where Daybook = ?"
End Sub
```

The Querytable itself starts in D3.
I also tried to run the above using `where Daybook = dbk`, same error.
If I remove the `where` clause or use a constant (`='somestring'`), I can refresh the QT without issue.

---

Note: the QT itself was created using this piece of code:

```
    sConn = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;Password=;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & _
        ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

    Set qt = ActiveCell.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=sConn, Destination:=ActiveCell)
    With qt
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = SQL
        .Name = Int((1000000000 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Comment: I do not know how to add a parameter to a query table but It seems to me that your error is an SQL error.

it should be "where Daybook = 'dbk' " and not " = dbk". The quote will make the where contidion suceed or not. Which is why without the quote you do not get an error but you also do not get a result. Nothing matches "dbk" without the quotes.

Comment: @GTPV that's my question...how to formulate the WHERE to refer to a parameter.

Comment: Have you tried to replace qt.Parameters.Add("dbk") by qt.Parameters.Add("'dbk'") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to have Parameters working was to use an ODBC connection instead of the OLEDB connection. In other words, just replace the connection string in the example by:

```
sConn = "ODBC;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";"
```

and the parameter adding code worked like magic.

**Edit:** not still fantastic... seems prone to issue with long paths and of course when file is moved. Not sure I am going to go further in that direction.